# how to create custom activity in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to create a custom activity in Marketing cloud so how can I create it ?
please suggest me .

Thanks & Regards 
Rajan Gupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit too broad and it'll be hard to help you out in detail. However, if you try to develop a custom activity for Journey Builder, I put together an example and documented the steps you need to do before using it.

This is **example code** for a custom split activity for journey builder, that reads data from Sales/Service Cloud: [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Service Cloud Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)

According to Salesforce the prerequisites for developing a custom activity are the following:

> - A working knowledge of RequireJS for dependency management
> - A working knowledge of jQuery
> - An understanding of the Postmonger event framework
> - Access to a Marketing Cloud account with a fully provisioned and operational Journey Builder instance
> - An understanding of how journeys function in Journey Builder
>
> (Source: [Salesforce Developer Documentation - Build Custom Activities and Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm))

**In short you need to do the following things:**

1. Set up a package in Marketing Cloud App Center
2. Build the Activity

   - Configuration
   - User Interface
   - Activity JavaScript (Communication between Journey Builder and the activity itself)
   - Backend that handles subscribers reaching your activity
3. Host the activity on a web server

Before starting you might like to read the following documentation articles, that cover quite a bit of that topic:

- [Create a Marketing Cloud App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/create-a-mc-app.htm)
- [Extend Journey Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/getting-started.htm)
- [Build Custom Activities and Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)
- [How Data Binding Works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm)